# convert multiple categories to single ones in panda dataframe

Tags: python, list, categories

In a column (product_type) of a panda datafrme, some has one type like "R", some has multiple types like "R, P, Q..." which means the product belongs to multiple types. How to assign the product to multiple types (categories)? Does it need to increase the length (rows) of the dataframe?

I used:

df['product_type_single_cat'] = df.product_type.str.split(',')
df.product_type_single_cat.head()

and get:

```
0    [Q, B]
1    [J, D]
2    [J, D]
3       [U]
4    [D, R]
```

I want to get:

0    Q
1    B
2    J
3    D
4    J

```
0    Q
1    B
2    J
3    D
4    J
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit unclear what you are trying to achieve based on the information provided.
However, I think this is what you are wanting to do.

Say you have a dataframe like this:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'product_type_single_cat':[['Q','B'],['J','D'],['J','D'],['U'],['D','R']]})

print(df)
```

```
  product_type_single_cat
0                  [Q, B]
1                  [J, D]
2                  [J, D]
3                     [U]
4                  [D, R]
```

To get these all on their own row, you could do this:

#### Code:

```
new_df = df.explode('product_type_single_cat')

print(new_df)
```

#### Output:

```
  product_type_single_cat
0                       Q
0                       B
1                       J
1                       D
2                       J
2                       D
3                       U
4                       D
4                       R
```